# How to encrypt or hide response data in Chrome developer tools or IE using https?

Tags: iis, https, response-headers

Hi Have installed **SSL certificate** with my application **Https** is working fine but when i am checking it in the developer tool all data is showing. I want to hide or encrypt the response data.
when i am debugging it in fiddler response data and header are encrypted which is according to my requirement. I am using **IIS** to host my application.

Comment: "when i am debugging it in fiddler response data and header are encrypted" is just an illusion. Fiddler can reveal the contents if you wish. However, the browser's developer tools and Fiddler use different mechanisms. So forget about "hide response data", as you simply cannot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the https is used for secure communication over a computer network. That means it is used to make the communication to be more security. The hacker couldn't capture the information during the communication.

If you use the browser as the client to send the request to the server, that means your client is not a hacker which will have the right certificate, so your client browser could see the right response from the server. That's make sense.

As lex says that you could also get the fiddle's details information by using the fiddler decrypt HTTPS feature.

Details ,you could refer to this [article](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS).